# Handling cookiejar from requests library python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, python-requests, cookiejar

I'm having a problem with retrieving cookies from a cookiejar.

I'm trying to use the requests library, and I want to retrieve a specific cookie, but I don't know how to.

Maybe one of you have more experience than I do or maybe knows more about Python2.7 and can help me out :)

Example:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('url')
print r.cookies
```

I'd like to handle this like a list or an array, so I can just get the value of a specific cookie.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the value of a specific cookie (that you know by name), then as per the [Python Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) it is possible to access this just like a dictionary:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('url')
r.cookies['cookie_name']
```

If, as you say, you'd like them as a list then you can use `r.cookies.keys()` to return a list of all the keys (cookie names) which you can then access as per the above, or just `r.cookies.values()` to get a list of all the values.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that 'url' is a complete url e.g. 'http://example.com'

The cookies are stored as a dictionary.  To access a specific cookie:

```
r.cookies['example_cookie_name']
```

[More from the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 49, in <module>
    print r['2']['__cfuid']
  File "D:\Program\Python2\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 276, in
__getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "D:\Program\Python2\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 331, in
_find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='__cfuid', domain=None, path=None"

Comment: Are you sure there is a 'cfuid' cookie?  print r.cookies.keys() to see the full list of cookies.